# Pass a 2D array

Tags: c++

I'm a bit confused about passing a 2D array.
Example:

```
void out(int **a){.....};
void out2(int a[][] ){......};
main () { 
    int arra[2][5];
    out (arra);
    out2(arra); 
}
```

Can I pass the array in both ways ?
What is the best way to pass a 2D array and why?

Comment: void out2( int a[][5] ) is the way, but maybe you should use std::array ?

Comment: i never used std::array. When i try to pass in the first way i get :  void out(int **)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [2][3]' to 'int **'

Comment: i told you the way, you must use array syntax and specify every dim but the first

Answer (score 0):

You may pass array by reference with this ugly syntax:

```
void out3(int (&a)[2][5]){}
main () { int a[2][5]; out3(a); }
```

Better to use `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 2>` or `std::vector`.

Comment: what is the & for ? `void out3(int a[2][5])` works fine, but yeah, definitely using std instead is better

Comment: @Guiroux: `void out3(int a[2][5])` is in fact `void out3(int (*a)[5])`. So you can pass `int a[3][5]` where the reference one doesn't allow that.

Comment: Ok so i have to use std::array or use a pointer to pointer  : int ** a(for the first case);

Comment: @Geech: You can't use a pointer to pointer, since there are no pointers to point to, only arrays.